# Proving the convergence of this sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

So I've asked myself the question "If a sequence converges, does the series of distances between the consecutive elements converge?". As a countexample I came up with the idea of a sequence constructed in this way:

Let $ a_1 = 1 $. $ a_2 = a_1 - \frac{1}{2} $. $ a_3 = a_2 - \frac{1}{3} $. So, generally, as we move further into the sequence we subtract consecutive elements of the harmonic sequence until we get the first negative term. Then we start adding them until we obtain a positive element, at which point we switch to  subtracting again.
$ a_4 = \frac{1}{4}, a_5 = a_4 - \frac{1}{5} $, so $ a_5 $ is negative. Now we add:
$ a_6 = a_5 + \frac{1}{6} $ and so on.

We will infinitely keep going between positive and negative side, because harmonic series is divergent. It seems to me that this sequence will converge to $ 0 $, because we keep oscillating with lower and lower "amplitude", but I don't have any good idea about proving this formally. If we establish that, it's obvious that the series of distances between consecutive elements is just the harmonic series, which diverges.

Any hints?

Comment: The series of differences $\sum_n (a_{n+1}- a_n) $ has as partial sums the sequence $a_{n+1} - a_1$.

Comment: I'm interested in the divergence of the series of distances, which are absolute values of differences.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you are dealing with convergent vs absolutely convergent series. Your ideas seem good. There are many of examples of such series.

Comment: It's easier to prove that the series of distances diverges for $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$.